# what is this color map? cmap=mglearn.cm3

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I try to run  the following code but it gives the following error in recognistion of mglearn color map.

grr = pd.scatter_matrix( ...., cmap=mglearn.cm3)

ErrorName: name 'mglearn' is not defined

I should add pd is Anaconda Pandas package imported as pd but does not recognize the color map mglearn.cm3

Any suggestions?

Comment: Python is telling you that your code does not define "mglearn" anywhere. It sounds like you're trying to use a module called "mglearn" without importing it.

Comment: If `mglearn.cm3` is a file it should be in quotes.

Comment: I got it. It can be installed using pip

Answer (score 4):

Open Anaconda prompt and execute `pip install mglearn`
After that just import mglearn

```
import pandas as pd
import mglearn
iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)
grr = pd.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=y_train, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o',s=60, alpha=0.8, hist_kwds={'bins': 10},cmap=mglearn.cm3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Concerns the code for the book - Introduction to Machine Learning with Python

1. At the top of the Code for the book (notebooks, etc.) there is a package folder named - mglearn. It contains, as its fist .py file - **init**.py.
2. It therefore allowed me to simply copy/paste the folder - mglearn, into my
   C:\Users\Ernesto\Anaconda3 folder and afterwards type - import mglearn - in my Spyder 3.5 editor.
3. Then the line:

   ```
   grr = pd.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe,
                           c=y_train, 
                           figsize=(15, 15),
                           marker='o',
                           hist_kwds={'bins': 20},
                           s=60, 
                           alpha=0.8, 
                           cmap=mglearn.cm3)
   ```

   prints the scatter_matrix just as in the book.

Answer (score 0):

1. conda install pip(because conda install mglearn will give a error)
2. pip install mglearn
3. grr = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix( ...., cmap=mglearn.cm3)
   if you still can't see the output then you might have missed `%matplotlib inline`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `mglearn` package. You can do that by running the below command in your Command Prompt or in the terminal (Anaconda/ any other IDE that has support for Terminal).

`pip install mglearn`

For more details on mglearn package visit: [enter link description here](https://pypi.org/project/mglearn/)

Answer (score 0):

if you are working in jupyter notebook just use cmap='PuBu' in scatter_matrix()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).